# Circularly shifting a vector

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, matrix, vector

I have a vector which is like

```
x = [20 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
```

I would like to shift the vector values as given

```
if (i = 1)
X = [11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20]

if (i = 2)
X = [12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 11]

if (i = 3)
X = [13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 11 12]
```

At present I am using a `for` loop to do this, but it takes a lot of time

```
x  = [20 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19];
in = x;
C1 = x;

for lt = 1:1:length(in)
    C1 = x ; 

    if (lt > 1) 
        for tt = 1:1:lt-1
            swap = C1(1);

            for pt = 1:1:length(in)-1
                C1(pt) = C1(pt+1);    
            end   

            C1(length(in)) = swap;
        end
    end    

    disp(C1);
end
```

Could some one please suggest me a faster algorithm?

Answer (score 5):

Let `s` denote the number of positions you want to shift. You can use [`circshift`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html):

```
x_shifted = circshift(x, [1 -s]);
```

The second argument is `[1 -s]` because you want to shift `s` positions to the *left* in the *second* dimension (columns).

You can also do it manually with [`mod`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html):

```
x_shifted = x(mod((1:numel(x))+s-1, numel(x))+1);
```

Comment: Well I think I just made a `bsxfun` version of your `mod` solution... hope that's okay!

Answer (score 4):

`circshift` is the way to go but you could also do it with pretty simple indexing:

```
x_shifted = x([(i+1):end , 1:(i-1)])
```

This however assumes that `1 < i  && i < length(x)`.

Comment: Simpler than using `mod`

Answer (score 2):

You could pre-calculate all `C1`'s in one go (vectorized manner) before the start of the loop(s) and use their values inside the loop(s) directly with indexing alone and thus save time on calculating them -

```
N = numel(x);
C1_all = x(mod(bsxfun(@plus,[0:N-1]',0:N-1),N)+1)
```

Code run for given `x` -

```
C1_all =
    20    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19
    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20
    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    11
    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    11    12
    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    11    12    13
    15    16    17    18    19    20    11    12    13    14
    16    17    18    19    20    11    12    13    14    15
    17    18    19    20    11    12    13    14    15    16
    18    19    20    11    12    13    14    15    16    17
    19    20    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18
```

Comment: Good solution.  I thought it was interesting that inside `hankel` ([like rayryeng's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28073572/2778484)), it does just what you did.

Comment: @chappjc Interesting to find out that! Not much of a `hankel` person though ;) Thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 1):

I can also suggest using [`hankel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hankel.html).  You can use `hankel` to generate a set of indices that you would use to index into `x` where each row gives you the circular shift amount you're looking for.  Something like this:

```
x = [20 11:19];
c = x(hankel([1:numel(x)], [numel(x) 1:numel(x)-1]))

c =

    20    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19
    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20
    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    11
    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    11    12
    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    11    12    13
    15    16    17    18    19    20    11    12    13    14
    16    17    18    19    20    11    12    13    14    15
    17    18    19    20    11    12    13    14    15    16
    18    19    20    11    12    13    14    15    16    17
    19    20    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18
```

Comment: Much cleaner than the `bsxfun` solution, but interestingly, `hankel` uses `bsxfun(@plus,...)` internally like Divakar did, but without the fuss of difficult syntax.  Difficult for the novice, I should say.  :) +1 to both you and Divakar.

Comment: @chappjc - Huh!  What do you know.  I've never taken the opportunity to look at the source.  Definitely good to know.  Thanks :)